# EventEmitter vs funciones

Tags: javascript, nodejs, funciones, events

Tengo una duda, cual es la diferencia entre usar un eventemitter y una funcion? pongo un ejemplo:

```
eventEmitter.on('suma', (num1, num2) => {
    console.log(num1 + num2)
})
eventEmitter.emit('suma', 10, 5)


const suma = (num1, num2) => {
    console.log(num1 + num2)
} 
suma(5, 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Los EventEmitters tienen varias ventajas respecto a las funciones normales.

#### 1. Varios listeners para un solo evento.

Puedes realizar distintas acciones en diferentes partes de tu aplicación usando EventEmitters emitiendo un único evento.

*Ejemplo:*
En un archivo emitter.js puedes exportar un EventEmitter que importaremos desde distantas partes de nuestro código.

```
const emitter = new EventEmitter();
module.exports = emitter;
```

Luego, supongamos que tenemos una aplicación de mensajería y un usuario manda un mensaje.

```
// chat.js
const emitter = requrie("./emitter")
emitter.emit("user_msg", "Esto es un mensaje.");
```

Este mensaje lo queremos mostrar en nuestra interfaz de usuario.

```
// handler.js
const emitter = require("./emitter");
emitter.on("user_msg", (data) => { addMessage(data) });
```

Y si además queremos mandar una notificación a todos los usuarios desde otro archivo:

```
// notifications.js
const emitter = require("./emitter");
emitter.on("user_msg", (data) => { sendNotification(data) });
```

Esto es solo un ejemplo sencillo y sin mucho sentido.

#### 2. Eventos de una sola ejecución.

Con los emitters podemos ejecutar una función una única vez por muchas veces que se emita el evento.

```
emitter.once("example", (data) => {
   // Este código solo se ejecutara una vez
});
```

#### 3. prependListener()

Con la función `emitter.prependListener("event", () => {})` puedes ejecutar una función antes de que se ejecute cualquier listener que hayas creado, independientemente del orden en el que se declaren en tu código, sin necesidad de añadir lógica adicional en el emisor.

Esto son solo unas pocas ventajas que se me han ocurrido viendo [la documentación oficial de node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html)

Espero que te haya servido!

Answer (score 1):

Intentaré responder en términos generales, porque pienso que tu pregunta tiene un fondo mas abstracto que práctico.

Por tu código me queda claro que sabes lo que es una función. Es una agrupación de instrucciones, donde se puede o no retornar un valor. Al menos en la programación orientada a objetos se la asocia con una `acción`, por está razón generalmente se les nombra con un verbo. Cuando programas vas creando funciones que se van llamando unas a otras, donde (por decirlo de una manera fácil) tienes cierta secuencialidad en el código.

Los eventos por otro lado son "cosas que suceden", en general son gatillados por acciones fuera de tu control. Digamos que tienes un botón y quieres hacer "algo" cuando un usuario lo presiona. Tu no tienes control de cuando el usuario lo va a presionar, esta acción escapará al flujo secuencial de tu código. En estos casos tu te subscribes (o escuchas) la emisión del evento que se gatilla cuando el usuario presionó aquel botón. Por supuesto, esto lo haces asociando una (o muchas) funciones a dicho evento